# How can two different class extend same class return same type in Scala

Tags: scala, type-mismatch

I'd like to be able to do something like this:

Suppose we have two Scala packages `A` and `B`. In `B`, I have two classes, like this:

```
class Structure{
    case class StructureA(x:String, y:String)
    case class StructureB(x:Int, y:Int)
}
class OperationB extend Structure{
    def optB(someData:String): Array[(StructureA,StructureB)] = {...}
}
```

and in `A`, I have one class like this:

```
import B.Structure
class OperationA extend Structure {
    def optA(data:Array[(StructureA,StructureB)]): Array[(StructureA,StructureB)] = {...}
}
```

And below is my project entry:

```
import B.{Structure,OperationB }
import A.OperationA
object Main {
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = { 


        val BInstance = new OperationB()
        val BResult = BInstance.optB(someData)

        val AInstance = new OperationA()
        val AResult = AInstance.optA(BResult)

    }
}
```

The problem is:

BResult is typeof Array[(StructureA,StructureB)] but it can't be compiled, the error message is

```
type mismatch, expected Array[(A.StructureA,A.StructureB)] actual Array[(B.StructureA,B.StructureB)]
```

Actually I add this code in it, and it can be compiled successfully, but I think that is not the best solution.

```
   import B.{Structure,OperationB }
   import A.OperationA
   object Main {
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = { 


        val BInstance = new OperationB()
        val AInstance = new OperationA()

        // here convert it into proper type.
        val BResult = BInstance.optB(someData).map{
            case (a,b) => (a.asInstanceOf[AInstance.StructureA],b.asInstanceOf[AInstance.StructureB])
        }


        val AResult = AInstance.optA(BResult)

    }
}
```

It has been bothering me for a long time, anyone can help me ?

Comment: Why do you need to have `StructureA`/`StructureB` inner classes? Is there a `Structure` in package `A` too? (Is this an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)?)

Comment: I use StructureA/StructureB to take them as a data container,  and there's nothing else in package A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code makes each instance of `Structure` get its own `StructureA` and `StructureB` types. Since they don't access `Structure`, there's no point doing so. Trying to extend `Structure` to save on imports is just a bad idea.

Instead

```
package structure // or could be B.structure, or directly B
case class StructureA(x:String, y:String)
case class StructureB(x:Int, y:Int)

// in A
package A
import structure._
class OperationA {
    def optA(data:Array[(StructureA,StructureB)]): Array[(StructureA,StructureB)] = {...}
}

// in B
package B
import structure._
class OperationB {
    def optB(someData:String): Array[(StructureA,StructureB)] = {...}
}
```

Another option is

```
object Structure {
    case class StructureA(x:String, y:String)
    case class StructureB(x:Int, y:Int)
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Your solution works fine, I think it is a bad idea to extend Structure to save on imports, and what I want to do at the beginning was to  declare data container, so other class can extend it to get the container case class.